# sql cast syntax

Tags: sql, pandasql

Having trouble with cast syntax. I get an error message with this and I am having trouble figuring out what the problem is. I'm using pandasql.

```
SELECT CAST((((male_year_df.total_male_suicides) / female_year_df.total_female_suicides)) AS DECIMAL(1,5)) AS male_female_ratio), male_year_df.year
```

EDIT: this is the error message:
OperationalError: near ")": syntax error

Comment: "I get an error message" why are you making us guess what the error message is? Include it in your question. Also, what is a `DECIMAL(1,5)`, 1 digit long, 5 of which on the right side of the decimal point? Makes little sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your parethesis are too much of, also `DECIMAL(1,5)` is not allowed as the first number has to be equal or bigger than the second number

```
SELECT CAST(
            
              (
                (male_year_df.total_male_suicides) 
                / (female_year_df.total_female_suicides)
            ) AS DECIMAL(5,5)) AS male_female_ratio
              , male_year_df.year
```

You can first define the firsst number with the precision you need and then divide the second number, so that the engine will not use integer division

```
 SELECT CAST(male_year_df.total_male_suicides AS DECIMAL(5,5)) 
     / (female_year_df.total_female_suicides) AS male_female_ratio
              , male_year_df.year
```

Comment: it works, but it's giving me whole numbers and rounding them, how do I get it to have 5 places after the decimal point?

Comment: so I use AS FLOAT instead of decimal and it's giving me values like 2.0 and 3.0, it's not giving me the precise numbers after the decimal.

Comment: then use DECIMAL(5,5) on the first numnber so that Integer dision will not be used

Comment: ok that worked. I used float instead of decimal, but yeah I used it on the first number. thanks!